# Time comparison in Excel

Tags: excel, time, excel-formula, formula

This should be straight-forward, I'm trying to compare if a value of time is less (or more) than another.

```
    =IF(A1 > B1,True,False)
```

Where A1 and B1 are a number of hours and minutes in [h]:mm format.

```
A1 is 48:45 in [h]:mm format
B1 is 50:00 in [h]:mm format
```

If I wanted to replace B1, in the formula, with an absolute time (say of fifty hours) than I thought the answer might be either:

```
 =IF(A1 > TEXT("50:00", "[h]:mm"),True,False)
 =IF(A1 > TIME(50,00,0),True,False)
```

But it's not. Any ideas?

Comment: Semi off topic **but** you can drop the `IF` and just do `A1 > B1`. This will evaluate to `TRUE` or `FALSE` naturally.

Comment: The True and False flags are actually text. I just swapped them to make more sense for the question. :)

Comment: If possible please share some sample data in `A1` and `B1`. I guess, you'll need to convert A1 into numerical form and then compare it with `50`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

TEXT returns Text and not a number and as such it would always be greater than the time.

But we can turn it into a number by simple multiplying it by `-1*-1`

```
=A1>--TEXT("50:00", "[h]:mm")
```

But then the simple would also work:

```
=A1>--"50:00"
```

---

TIME returns the time portion and as such:

> `TIME(50,00,0)`

resolves to `2:00` or `0.0833333` as it is the time part of the number without the integer.

So we can just do some simple math:

```
=A1 > 50/24
```

now the `50/24` will resolve properly to `2.083333`

[image]

Answer (score 3):

The [`VALUE`](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/value-function-257d0108-07dc-437d-ae1c-bc2d3953d8c2) function can come in handy for you. It's the build-in function to turn text-strings that represent a numeric value into an actual numeric value, so:

```
=A1>VALUE("50:00")
```

Comment: less typing with `--`. :)

Comment: Haha, yes true @ScottCraner, but nonetheless a good alternative as it's a function specifically designed for the task :)